# CentOS 7 disable predictable network interface names during install

Tags: networking, redhat, centos7, systemd

I know I can use `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0`, with `grub`, to disable [predictable network interface names](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). This names the first interface as eth0 instead of enp0s3, or whatever. How do I specify this at install time using a kickstart file?

Comment: If possible you should avoid doing this entirely. Predictable network device names have many advantages over the old system, especially for administrators.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Right but currently the consistent naming is far from consistent. There's some interesting discussion here but I couldn't find my specific answer on this thread: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/644133

Comment: All of those comments applied (1) to the beta, and (2) to virtual machines. They have long since been fixed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm still getting enp0s3, enp0s8, enp0s9, enp0s11 using vagrant/virtual box as of CentOS 7.1 (1503).

Comment: Well, you can't expect VirtualBox to be consistent. It's not like that's a serious virtualization platform.

Comment: Maybe you could try with my the answer at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671396/what-does-eno-stand-for-in-network-device-name-eno16777736-on-centos-7-or-rh/36503043#36503043

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the [bootloader](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-kickstart-syntax.html#idp14219936) section in the kickstart file to suppress predictable network interface names. Adding `net.ifnames=0` and [if needed] `biosdevname=0` to the `--append` should do what you're asking.

```
bootloader --location=mbr --append="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

Note that I've excluded the defaults `rhgb quiet crashkernel=auto` from the `--append`, it will work with or without them. You may also exclude the biosdevname package from install and use only `net.ifnames=0` in the above.

```
bootloader --location=mbr --append="net.ifnames=0"
...
%packages --nobase
@core --nodefaults
-biosdevname
%end
```

Comment: Are the `rhgb quiet crashkernel...` parameters necessary or can I just do `--append="net.ifnames=0"`?

Comment: I have not tested it without `rhgb quiet crashkernel`, as they were defaults, but none of them should be required to have a booting install.

Comment: Worked with just `--append="net.ifnames=0"` and `-biosdevname` under packages.

Comment: @jscott

rhgb provides splash screen.

quiet provides you a "silent" boot, if you remove it from bootloader, boot will be more verbose.

crashkernel is used by kdump, you can remove it if you have kdump disabled or uninstalled.